# Install Prefer `devDependencies` Over Conflicting `dependencies`

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have a scenario where I want to develop/QA against a different version of the same package that is used on production. I'm trying to manage this in a single `package.json` file. However, when I add a package to `dependencies` and `devDependencies` with different versions, the `npm install` command prefers the version specified at `dependencies`. Is there a way to get it to prefer the version installed at `devDependencies`? Or is there perhaps a different/better way to manage this scenario?

Comment: I added [this issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/15360) if you want to push for it too.

Answer (score 0):

`npm link` is the preferred solution to this problem.